# How to show only one result if it is not unique in a Jquery Autocomplete and Django

Tags: python, django, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I just finished adding an autocomplete with Jquery in my Django project and it seems to be working fine by showing me the result. The only problem is that I want to search by destination, not title and since I have multiple objects that have the same destination value and my autocomplete is set up to show 5 results, I get 5 time the same result. How can set this up to make the autocomplete show only one result if it is not unique.

Here's a link to the image of the problem:

[image]

I use this custom Javascript code for the autocomplete:

```
$(function () {
    'use strict';

    $('#q').autocomplete({
    serviceUrl: "http://127.0.0.1:8000/search/autocomplete/",
    minChars: 2,
    dataType: 'json',
    type: 'GET',
    onSelect: function (suggestion) {
        console.log( suggestion.value + ', data :' + suggestion.data);
    }
});

});
```

My **Views.py** autocomplete function:

```
def autocomplete(request):
    sqs = SearchQuerySet().autocomplete(
        content_auto=request.GET.get(
            'query',
            ''))[
        :5]
    s = []
    for result in sqs:
        d = {"value": result.destination, "data": result.object.slug}
        s.append(d)
    output = {'suggestions': s}
    return JsonResponse(output)
```

My **Models.py**:

```
class Product(models.Model):

    destination = models.CharField(max_length=255, default='')

    title = models.CharField(max_length=255, default='')
    slug = models.SlugField(null=True, blank=True, unique=True, max_length=255, default='')
    description = models.TextField(default='')

    ptags = TaggableManager()

    image = models.ImageField(default='')
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    def _ptags(self):
        return [t.name for t in self.ptags.all()]

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('product',
                       kwargs={'slug': self.slug})


    def __str__(self):
        return self.destination
```

And in my Urls:

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.contrib import admin
from search.views import HomeView, ProductView, FacetedSearchView, autocomplete
from .settings import MEDIA_ROOT, MEDIA_URL
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', HomeView.as_view()),
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^product/(?P<slug>[\w-]+)/$', ProductView.as_view(), name='product'),
    url(r'^search/autocomplete/$', autocomplete),
    url(r'^search/', FacetedSearchView.as_view(), name='haystack_search'),

] + static(MEDIA_URL, document_root=MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Here's my **search_indexes.py** file:

```
import datetime
from django.utils import timezone
from haystack import indexes
from haystack.fields import CharField

from .models import Product


class ProductIndex(indexes.SearchIndex, indexes.Indexable):
    text = indexes.EdgeNgramField(
        document=True, use_template=True,
        template_name='C:/Users/loicq/Desktop/Coding/UVERGO_SEARCH/venv/src/templates/search/indexes/product_text.txt')
    title = indexes.CharField(model_attr='title')
    description = indexes.EdgeNgramField(model_attr="description")
    destination = indexes.EdgeNgramField(model_attr="destination")
    image = indexes.CharField(model_attr="image")


    # Tags
    ptags = indexes.MultiValueField(model_attr='_ptags', faceted=True)

    # for auto complete
    content_auto = indexes.EdgeNgramField(model_attr='destination')

    # Spelling suggestions
    suggestions = indexes.FacetCharField()

    def get_model(self):
        return Product

    def index_queryset(self, using=None):
        """Used when the entire index for model is updated."""
        return self.get_model().objects.filter(timestamp__lte=timezone.now())
```

Any solutions?

Comment: It looks like you are using Haystack (right?), so you probably need to change the definition of `content_auto` in your SearchIndex.  Can you include that?

Comment: Yes I do and thanks for the answer I'm updating the question with my search index file now.

Comment: Updated the question

Comment: It depends a bit on what you want.  You are getting 5 products as your result.  Would it make sense to display Product 1 - Las Vegas, Product 2 - Las Vegas,... or do you just want the destination without any interest in the products?

Comment: I only need the destination without any interest in the products since users will get results for all the products in a given destination.

Comment: I mean the actual search results are the products but the autocomplete is the destination only.

Comment: So do you want to show the products in the results?

Comment: Not inside of the autocomplete, only the destination value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will include the product title in the autocomplete:

```
for result in sqs:
    d = {
        "value": " - ".join((result.destination, result.title)),
        "data": result.object.slug,
    }
```

But if you are really not interested in the product, you probably don't want `result.object.slug` in the `data`.  I guess you will go to some view for the destination, so some identifier for the destination belongs in there.  It is probably better to build a separate index for the destinations, but you could just extract them like this, using a set comprehension and a list comprehension:

```
def autocomplete(request):
    sqs = SearchQuerySet().autocomplete(
        content_auto=request.GET.get('query',''))[:5]
    destinations = {result.destination for result in sqs}
    s = [{"value": dest, "data": dest} for dest in destinations]
    output = {'suggestions': s}
    return JsonResponse(output)
```

I've assumed you don't need to keep the order (as that is based on the products).  You might want to get more than 5 results up front and then trim later, to have more chance of 5 *distinct* destinations.